# Cant move previously created child

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have used action-script 3 to create a child named bullet every time I click. It works when i first click and I can move it by adding 1 to the bullets x velocity but then when I click again to add a new child the new one i have added does not move. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a answer! You need to add it to a array then use 'arrayname'[b].x+=1 to move it!

Answer (score 0):

You've lost reference to object when create new object and assing it to your old reference. You have to keep reference in the array, like you did, or better way is to create new class for you bullet encapsulating its behavior. Then you just create object of your class and it moves itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is something like this:

I walk into a room with two people. One is named John Smith and one is John Robinson. You give me a cupcake and say, "Would you please give this to John?", and immediately leave. I have no idea which John you mean, so I just give it to John Smith.

When you try to name these bullets both `bullet`, AS3 will only ever remember one of them by the name "`bullet`". A name can reference only one object. Instead, let's create an array that contains all of our bullets, and whenever we need to do something to all the bullets, we'll just access every item in the array!

```
var bulletArray:Array = []

function updateBullets()  {
    //repeat an action for every item in bulletArray
    for (var i=0;i<bulletArray.length;i++) {
        var targetBullet = bulletArray[i]
        targetBullet.x += 1
        //anything else we want to do goes here
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you create a new bullet, also add it to the `bulletArray`!